# Postgres copy to command sendmail

Tags: postgresql, copy, sendmail

I am trying to send an html email via Postgres/Redhat/sendmail

Here is my Postgres copy command

```sql
copy
  (Select 'Subject: This is the subject'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Content-Type: text/html'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  email_body from sometable)
to program
  'sendmail -f aaa@aaa.com aaa@aaa.com'
with (
  format text);
```

The emails are sending but certain lines are ending with exclamation points when I look at the email html source, which is messing up the html emails.  There are no exclamation points in my original html and I have done everything possible to rule out line endings.   I even put a regex in the SQL to remove all non-printable characters but the esclamation point still come through.

Anybody have an idea why Postgres/sendmail would add exclamation points?  They seem to start appearing around the css in the generated html.

This is for a restricted environment so please do not suggest any other mail tools.  I am limited to sendmail.

**html from my table.**

```html
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><HEAD><style type="text/css"> .body, p, ul, li, ol, h1, h2, a, b, strong  {color: #FFFFFF; font-family: 'Citi-Sans-Display-Regular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } .body, p, ul, li, ol { color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 1.2; } body,td,th { color: #FFFFFF; } a { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: none;} a:link { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: none;} a:visited { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: none;} a:hover { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: underline;} a:active { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: none;} .blue{ color: #00bdf2} .div-header { background-color: #0F1632; } .div-sub-header { background-color: #255BE3; } table.blueTable { font-family: 'Citi-Sans-Display-Regular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 0px solid #73C2FC; background-color: #EEEEEE; width: 100%; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse; } table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th { border: 1px solid #AAAAAA; padding: 3px 2px; } table.blueTable tbody td { font-size: 13px; color: #53565a } table.blueTable tr:nth-child(even) { background: #FFFFFF; }  table.blueTable thead { background: #73C2FC; border-bottom: 2px solid #444444; text-align: center; } table.blueTable thead th { font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5; } table.blueTable thead th:first-child { border-left: none; }  table.blueTable tfoot { font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; background: #D0E4F5; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%); background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%); border-top: 2px solid #444444; } table.blueTable tfoot td { font-size: 14px; } table.blueTable tfoot .links { text-align: right; } table.blueTable tfoot .links a{ display: inline-block; background: #73C2FC; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 2px 8px; border-radius: 5px; }  </style> </HEAD> <body>test</body> </html>
```

**HTML that sendmail creates**:

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"><style type="text/css"> .body, p, ul, li, ol, h1, h2, a, b, strong  {color: #FFFFFF; font-family: 'Citi-Sans-Display-Regular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } .body, p, ul, li, ol { color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 1.2; } body,td,th { color: #FFFFFF; } a { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: none;} a:link { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: none;} a:visited { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: none;} a:hover { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: underline;} a:active { color: #00BDF2; text-decoration: none;} .blue{ color: #00bdf2} .div-header { background-color: #0F1632; } .div-sub-header { background-color: #255BE3; } table.blueTable { font-family: 'Citi-Sans-Display-Regular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 0px solid #73C2FC; background-color: #EEEEEE; width: 100%; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse; } table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th { bo!
 rder: 1px solid #AAAAAA; padding: 3px 2px; } table.blueTable tbody td { font-size: 13px; color: #53565a } table.blueTable tr:nth-child(even) { background: #FFFFFF; }  table.blueTable thead { background: #73C2FC; border-bottom: 2px solid #444444; text-align: center; } table.blueTable thead th { font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5; } table.blueTable thead th:first-child { border-left: none; }  table.blueTable tfoot { font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; background: #D0E4F5; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%); background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%); border-top: 2px solid #444444; } table.blueTable tfoot td { font-size: 14px; } table.blueTable tfoot .links { text-align: right; } table.blueTable tfoot .links a{ display: inline-block; background: #73C2FC; colo !
 r: #FFFFFF; padding: 2px 8px; border-radius: 5px; }  </style> !
 </head> <body>test</body> </html>
```

I tried removing all line endings, invisible characters, and only selecting printable characters from table.

Update

I was able to find the full solution that I was looking for.  The problem I was having is exclamations were being added to html due to the length of the string.   To get around the line limitation I used the fold command to get the html source to wrap.

```sql
      copy (Select 'Subject: This is the subject' 
      UNION ALL SELECT 'Content-Type: text/html' 
      UNION ALL SELECT replace(email_body,chr(10),'') from sometable) 
      to program 'fold -s | sendmail -f aaa@aaa.com aaa@aaa.com' with ( 
      format text);
'''
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi for the direction.   I found a work around from making modifications by using the "fold" command.   This allows the text not to get too long.

    copy
      (Select 'Subject: This is the subject'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Content-Type: text/html'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT  replace(email_body,chr(10),'') from sometable)
    to program
      'fold -s | sendmail -f aaa@aaa.com aaa@aaa.com'
    with (
      format text);

Comment: Thanks goes to @JGH who found the duplicate